# Using low-voltage, charged capacitor(s) to power integrated components

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging

I have a circuit that uses a small amount of current (500 uA). It can run from 2 to 4 volts, so the wattage is quite small.

I know that capacitors have well-defined charging and discharging rates. My question is, if you used the capacitor as a battery for a circuit with ICs, would this slow down its discharge rate to only supply as much current as the IC needed?

Or, would the capacitor "take control", over-supplying current to the IC, causing damage?

Is there any way to "control" or "limit" the amount of current from a discharging capacitor, so that it doesn't over-supply an IC, can last longer, and acts as a cheap, small, low-power rechargeable battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that capacitors have well-defined charging and discharging rates.

Yes. That rate is:

$$V(t) = \frac{Q(t)}{C} = \frac{1}{C}\int_{t_0}^t I(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau + V(t_0)$$

In practical terms, this means that the capacitor will discharge according to the *current* that the load pulls from it, in a rate defined by the capacitance *C*. Most textbooks go from there to the usual RC circuit special case:

$$V(t) = V_0 \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau_0}}\right)$$

But this *does not* reflect a constant-current circuit like you describe. For your circuit, you'd have to make *V(t0) = 4 V* and *I(τ) = -0.0005 A* and use the first equation to find out when you'd get 2V output. This will pretty much turn out to be a **straight line down**. How fast it will go down will depend on *C*.

Another important point is that most capacitors have instrinsic [leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(electronics)) that will discharge them even when they're not being used. This is a major factor for low-power applications.

Comment: I think Andy has a good idea.  Use a low power LDO adj to about 3.5 volts.  However, using a high voltage cap would I think, waste energy.  A 6.3 volt @ many uF should do.  Is it practical?  Maybe, but 3-4 D cells would give you a couple of hundred hours operation with less drama (but not as much fun).

Comment: Not really. For a 1F **ideal** (no ESR, no leakage) supercap, you'd get 2/0.0005 = 4000 **seconds** from 4 to 2V. That's a bit more than 1h. Making it 6.3V will get you 8600s. More voltage increases time linearly, at the expense of having to use a regulator, which will increase power consumption (look for quiescent current in datasheets). [Online calculator](http://www.circuits.dk/calculator_capacitor_discharge.htm).

Comment: My thinking was that for a given volume of capacitor(s) you would be better off increasing the uFs instead of increasing the voltage.  I didn't run the numbers.

Comment: 10F supercapacitor seems ideal for this use case? Such as https://www.sparkfun.com/products/746

Comment: Right, you suggested a supercap. Never seen that word before

Answer (score 3):

The current taken from the capacitor will only be that current needed by the load. It's ohms law. If the capacitor is charged to (say) 3 volts and the load normally takes 1 mA at 3 volts (3000 ohms) then it's the same when connecting that 3000 ohm load across a charged capacitor. The capacitor doesn't magically emit several amps the second something approaches it. Regard it as a battery with a very defined voltage discharge curve.

Consider also that you might get more life by using a voltage regulator and charging a significantly higher voltage onto the capacitor that feeds the voltage regulator. Use a low power buck regulator for even more life between charges. Do the math!

Maybe this buck regulator: -

[image]

[image]

It will work with an input voltage as low as 2.5 volts and up to 15 volts and introduce a power loss of about 0.33 mW. Given that the load is about about 1 mW, the losses do seem quite high but, if the capacitor is charged to say 12 volt I think there are significant gains to be made.

If you have a 1 farad supercap charged to 12 volts you can work out the discharge time based on Q = CV.

\$\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = C\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$ and this equals current.

So, with an overall current of say 1 mA, dv/dt = 0.001 (capacitance is 1 farad). Voltage discharges at a rate of about 1 mV per second. In an hour, the 12 volts will have dropped by 3,600 mV to 8.4 volts. After two hours (ignoring the fact that current will inevitably reduce towards more like 0.75 mA), the voltage will be 4.8 volts. A further 30 minutes and the terminal voltage is 3 volts.

So, conservatively, you should get a shade over 2.5 hours with a 1 farad supercap charged to 12 volts.

Given the low current requirement it should also work with a linear LDO regulator like the LT1761-2 (2 volt version): -

[image]

There is a 2 volt fixed output version that will work down to an input voltage of 2.5 volts. The quiescent current of the device is 20 uA so this actually looks ideal for what you want. Maximum input voltage is 20 volts but, if we used the 12 volt limit as used previously, the overall discharge current is 520 uA and not the assumed 1 mA. This nearly doubles the discharge time from a 1 farad supercap charged to 12 volts.

However, finding a 12 volt supercap is going to be problematic and one rated at 5.5 volts seems more likely. 1 farad charged to 5 volts being discharged with 0.52 mA will lower its terminal voltage by 0.52 mV every second. So, in one hour the total reduction will be 1.872 volts taking the 5 volts down to about 3.1 volts.

You would probably achieve 1.5 hours using a low power linear LDO voltage regulator (like the LT1761-2) and a 5.5 volt 1 farad supercap.